# test run react native app on iphone

Tags: react-native

I've signed developer account in xcode.

I connected iphone to mac.

I pressed cmd+b and it show built successful

Then what? How to make the app appear on iphone?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you connect your device then xcode checks if it's version matches with the device and if it matches then you just need to run the application from xcode by clicking the play button or `CTRL+b`. Then npm package runs through terminal and finally if the build is successful, the application automatically start running on your device.

Please have a look at the documentation: https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device

Answer (score 1):

You can always go the route of creating a dev server that is only accessed through your WiFi.

See the following:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html

Comment: My app just does one thing, show `hello world` text. Is there really the need for server?

Answer (score -1):

If you followed the steps on the [React Native website](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content), you will be able to do the following commands on the command line

first, `cd` to your project directory like this:

```
cd MyApp
```

then, once you are in the same directory as your app, start the app with the following command,:

```
react-native run-ios
```

This should do it, if not, it will tell you what you are missing.

UPDATE:

I didn't realize it was specific to a real device, in that case, just press the Play button on the top left, pressing Cmd + B just builds the app, press Cmd + R to run.

Comment: react-native run-ios will by default open simulator, but he want to run on real device, for that you need to run the app through xcode

Comment: That's running app on simulator on a computer. My question is about real iPhone

Comment: My bad, in that case, When you press Cmd + B you are just building the app, you now need to run it. To let Xcode do both for you just press the Play button on the top right corner, on the left of the selected device.